# How to send a message through telegram bot? [There is a solution, but something is wrong]

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot, mailing

I have a problem trying to send a message through the command. The fact is that the message comes only to me
Method:

```
        else if(text.startsWith("/add")){
          
           sendMessage.setText(message.getText());
            sendMessage.setParseMode("Markdown");
                for (Customer customer : Database.customerList) {
                    System.out.println(customer);
                     Long id = customer.getId();
                    sendMessage.setChatId(String.valueOf(id));
                }

            ComponentContainer.MY_TELEGRAM_BOT.sendMsg(sendMessage);
        }
```

I'm trying to send a message to all users through the processing of all id through the database, as a result, the message comes only to me